# Identifying Geolocation of user behind proxy

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I am writing an web application that requires the current geolocation of user. For identifying geolocation I have used the following code that uses HTML5 geolocation api. I have taken this code from W3schools.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
   var x=document.getElementById("demo");
   function getLocation()
    {
      if (navigator.geolocation)
        { 
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
         }
     else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }
   function showPosition(position)
    {
        x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
   "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;   
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have run this code with Tomcat, but it is not working
neither in Firefox nor in Chrome. Then I have tried this code with "Try It Yourself" in W3Schools and it is not working even there also neither in Firefox nor in Chrome. I am behind the proxy.

I have introduced an alert() statement at the start of body of the function showPosition() and it did not get called. So it seems this function is not getting called at all. I have no clue how to fix that. I desperately need to fix that. I have previously posted that problem but got no response probably because of not framing the problem clearly. So I am again posting the problem.

Is there any other way to get the geolocation of the users who are accessing this application throuogh computers. So please help. Thank you.

**EDIT**: I have hosted this file on Tomcat. Each time I am executing, it is giving error code 3 i.e. timeout. But I have executed the same Javascript two months back. Then it executed perfectly. Is it a problem with current version of my browser?

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing for the proxy to do with the html5 geolocation api, it's detecting location based on your gps device if you have one on your machine, second it goes to use the wifi device, finally it uses the internet ip to detect your location, and if you connecting using proxy it'll show the location of your proxy.
your issue may be because you didn't give the permission to the localhost on your browser, check it again and retry your code.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I don't know how to give permission to the localhost on my browser. Could you please clarify?

Comment: you can open your settings in chrome, and search for content settings, then scroll down to location options.

Comment: Yes Sir, I have checked but in Content Setting I found no such thing related to localhost.

Comment: @Joy can you open your console and check if you have any errors thrown ?

Comment: Actually Sir, nothing is getting printed in console. It seems that function showPosition is not getting called. I have no clue what is going on. I have introduced another alert() statement just before the line "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);". It seems to be the last statement executed.

Comment: Yes Sir, got it. Error code 3 is coming. But I have no idea how to fix this error.

Comment: @Joy one last check, are you running the page in a web context, or just from your disc?

Comment: I am running from Web Context, not from disk.

Comment: @Joy try this out https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation$samples/Geolocation_Live_Example?revision=388351

Comment: Yes I have tried it but, when I clicked on the button "Show my location" it is just printing "Locating..." and nothing else.

Comment: See I am using Firefox of version 16.0.2. Is there any problem with this version?

Comment: @Joy I'm using ff 21 and it's working fine with me, you may try using chrome. it's working fine too.

Comment: Have you executed in FF 16.0.2? So is it a browser related problem?

Comment: @Joy unfortunately i don't have ff 16 on my machine.